# d3js get data from multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, d3.js, multidimensional-array, pie-chart

I'm working on a d3js donut chart and I'm trying to feed data in from a multidimensional array: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juyLepnr/7/)

Output of topHoldersArray:

```
{
"1":{"address":"0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d","amount":"309953166.54621424","percent":"30.9953%"},
"2":{"address":"0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b","amount":"200000001","percent":"20.0000%"},
"3":{"address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","amount":"129336426","percent":"12.9336%"}
}
```

With this array I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'startAngle' of undefined
```

How can I feed this array into the graph? It seems the issue is that it's a multidimensional array but I"m not sure how to access it for the data points

Here's a snippet illustrating the problem:

```js
var topHoldersArray = [
{
  "1":{"address":"0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d","amount":"309953166","percent":"30.9953%"},
  "2":{"address":"0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b","amount":"200000001","percent":"20.0000%"},
  "3":{"address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","amount":"129336426","percent":"12.9336%"}
}
];

var data = topHoldersArray;
    
var text = "";

var width = 260;
var height = 260;
var thickness = 40;
var duration = 750;

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var svg = d3.select("#topHoldersChart")
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'pie')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height);

var g = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2) + ',' + (height/2) + ')');

var arc = d3.arc()
.innerRadius(radius - thickness)
.outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d) { return d.amount; })
.sort(null);

var path = g.selectAll('path')
.data(pie(data))
.enter()
.append("g")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
      let g = d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "text-group");
 
      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "name-text")
        .text(`${d.data.address}`)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '-1.2em');
  
      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "value-text")
        .text(`${d.data.amount}`)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '.6em');
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current))
        .select(".text-group").remove();
    })
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current));
    })
  .each(function(d, i) { this._current = i; });


g.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .text(text);
```

```css
.pie {
  margin: 20px;
}

.pie text {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  fill: #888;
}

.pie .name-text{
  font-size: 1em;
}

.pie .value-text{
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="token-chart">
  <h6>Top Holders</h6>
  <div class="chart" id="topHoldersChart"></div>
</div>
    

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your d3.pie layout:

```
var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d) { return d.amount; })
.sort(null);
```

When we feed data to this (`pie(data)`), pie is expecting an array. But you are providing an object:

```
{
"1":{"address":"0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d","amount":"309953166.54621424","percent":"30.9953%"},
"2":{"address":"0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b","amount":"200000001","percent":"20.0000%"},
"3":{"address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","amount":"129336426","percent":"12.9336%"}
}
```

We need to convert this to an array to feed it to `d3.pie()`. For this we could use `d3.entries()` (though there are other ways to achieve this too).

`d3.entries()` takes an object, say:

```
{ a: value1, b: value2 }
```

And converts it to an array:

```
[ { key: "a", value: value1 }, {key: "b", value: value2 } ]
```

The values are now within a property called `value`. This requires us to look up the amount at `d.value.amount`. For example:

```js
var topHoldersArray = 
{
  "1":{"address":"0xd35a2d8c651f3eba4f0a044db961b5b0ccf68a2d","amount":"309953166","percent":"30.9953%"},
  "2":{"address":"0xe17c20292b2f1b0ff887dc32a73c259fae25f03b","amount":"200000001","percent":"20.0000%"},
  "3":{"address":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","amount":"129336426","percent":"12.9336%"}
};

var data = d3.entries(topHoldersArray);

var text = "";

var width = 260;
var height = 260;
var thickness = 40;
var duration = 750;

var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var svg = d3.select("#topHoldersChart")
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'pie')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height);

var g = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2) + ',' + (height/2) + ')');

var arc = d3.arc()
.innerRadius(radius - thickness)
.outerRadius(radius);

var pie = d3.pie()
.value(function(d) { return d.value.amount; })
.sort(null);

var path = g.selectAll('path')
.data(pie(data))
.enter()
.append("g")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
      let g = d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "text-group");
 
      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "name-text")
        .text(`${d.data.value.address}`)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '-1.2em')
  
      g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "value-text")
        .text(`${d.data.value.amount}`)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '.6em')
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current))
        .select(".text-group").remove();
    })
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)     
        .style("cursor", "pointer")
        .style("fill", "black");
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
        .style("cursor", "none")  
        .style("fill", color(this._current));
    })
  .each(function(d, i) { this._current = i; });


g.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .text(text);
```

```css
.pie {
  margin: 20px;
}

.pie text {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  fill: #888;
}

.pie .name-text{
  font-size: 1em;
}

.pie .value-text{
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="token-chart">
  <h6>Top Holders</h6>
  <div class="chart" id="topHoldersChart"></div>
</div>
    

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but the graph didn't populate. I updated the OP to show the output of the topHoldersArray. Is it the same as what you expected?

Comment: I had assumed you had an array (as in the provided fiddle), I'll adjust for an object.

Comment: "If you feed the pie function an array of the child objects without placing them in the parent object" ... how can I convert the array through code to do this? thx again

Comment: @joeshmoe, I've updated the snippet to use an input object containing child objects representing each arc.